# Will Android Fast Emulator be supported by future AMD Zen processors?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, amd-processor

These days new excavator based CPUs for the new AM4 socket and chipset will be released, and at the last part of the year, the new Zen AMD processors are being released.

In the requisites for Android Fast Emulator I can read this: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Requirements

> For accelerated emulator: 64-bit operating system and Intel® processor
> with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute
> Disable (XD) Bit functionality

So.... are AMD users forgotten in the black hole of desperation? or will be supported by zen?

Comment: Ask AMD. I am not quite certain what you are expecting anyone else here to tell you, about future products from AMD.

Comment: I think it is not just a problem for AMD, Google has the capabilities to implement an optimized emulator also for AMD Cpu instruction sets and technologies, the problem is that I don't know if future AMD Zen processors will be suported by android fast emulation, so I'm asking it here, as it is not possible to ask it to google and here we have a huge and rich android hardcore developer community. Maybe someone knows something that you and me are not expecting